# Excepción al leer un String con Scanner

Tags: java, vscode, excepciones, scanner, acentos

Pues no sé por qué sucede, pero el programa que estoy haciendo me lanza una excepción al intentar leer un String introducido mediante la consola.

La excepción que lanza es la siguiente:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line
> found

Esto solo sucede cuando uno o más caracteres de una cadena tienen tilde o la letra 'ñ'.

¿Alguien sabría decirme cuál puede ser el problema?

Como solución, he probado a cambiar la codificación en la que el Scanner lee los datos, pero no ha funcionado:

```
Scanner consola = new Scanner(System.in, "Windows 1252");

String texto;

System.out.println("Introduce un texto");

texto = consola.nextLine();
```

Ese es el código que tengo, aunque no hay mucho que mostrar...

Comment: Deberías estar teniendo otro error antes si usas como codificación "Windows 1252", debe ser "Windows-1252"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es un problema del lenguaje java, es un problema del editor Visual Studio Code y la terminal que estés usando para ejecutar el programa de Java.

Me explico:

Visual Studio Code viene con una terminal integrada en la que se pueden ejecutar scripts de diferentes lenguajes de programación en función de los lenguajes que admita el editor y de las extensiones que se tengan instaladas.

Por "terminal integrada", me refiero a que la terminal se ve directamente en un espacio dedicado del editor en lugar de que se abra una ventana de terminal. Es decir, **no es** una terminal propia como pueda suceder con algunos IDE tales como Eclipse o NetBeans, sino que se usará una terminal que  puede cambiar en función del sistema operativo.

En muchas versiones de Windows, la terminal por defecto es el clásico "cmd" o "Command Prompt". Esta terminal, al menos en versiones antiguas de Windows, no es compatible con todas las [Páginas de códigos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page)

es decir, la codificación de los caracteres con los que se va a trabajar en la terminal. Solo es compatible con unos pocos tipos de codificación.

Una de las extensiones de Visual Studio Code para trabajar con Java es [Debugger for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-debug)

Esta extensión viene con un script.bat que se ejecuta cuando vas a ejecutar un script de java con el editor (es decir cuando pulsas F5 o Ctrl + F5). Lo hace justo antes de que se ejecute ninguna instrucción en java.

Este script.bat viene con un comando "chcp" que fuerza a la consola a utilizar una página de códigos concreta; UTF-8. Sin embargo, como la terminal "cmd" no es compatible con esa codificación, cuando ejecutas un programa en Java e intentas introducir un texto que tenga caracteres tales como letras con acentos o "ñ", la consola no reconoce esos caracteres, por lo tanto, java tampoco los reconoce y el programa lanzará la excepción:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
```

**Solución**

La solución para arreglar esto es modificar el script.bat que se ejecuta, para que la terminal use una página de códigos diferente.

El script se llama "launcher.bat" y se lanza cuando se ejecuta un programa de java a través del editor. El nombre del script así como la ruta en la que se encuentra se ve claramente en la terminal. Se puede hacer clic en el archivo directamente desde la terminal para modificarlo desde el editor.

En el archivo se encuentra la siguiente línea:

```
@chcp.com 65001 > NUL
```

El número se refiere a la página de códigos que utilizará la terminal, pues bien, ese número hay que cambiarlo por otro que haga referencia a una página de códigos compatible con la terminal y que además pueda admitir caracteres especiales tales como letras con acentos o la letra "ñ". Por ejemplo:

```
@chcp.com 1252 > NUL
```

Con esto se solucionará el problema de introducir ciertos caracteres especiales en la consola, pero estos caracteres aún no se mostrarán correctamente. Para que se muestren correctamente se debe indicar al objeto Scanner que utilice una codificación concreta, por ejemplo:

```
Scanner consola = new Scanner(System.in, "Windows-1252);
```

Con esto ya se podrá trabajar con normalidad con acentos en Java y el editor Visual Studio Code. Espero que a alguien le sirva de ayuda.

Por supuesto, otra posible solución sería cambiar la terminal que usa el editor por otra, pero eso ya es otra historia.

Answer (score 2):

El encoding debe ser "Windows-1252" (no "Windows 1252"), de otra forma podrás tener un error:

> java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException

considera usar la codificación "UTF-8" (o "ISO-8859-1") si es que usarás caracteres acentuados o con tilde del idioma español.

```
Scanner consola = new Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8");
```

Con respecto a el error que mencionas en tu pregunta:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line
> found

Estas tratando de obtener un valor del Scanner el cual no existe, puedes validar usando `hasNextLine()`:

```
while(consola.hasNextLine()){
    texto = consola.nextLine();
    ...
}
```

---

De acuerdo a el ejemplo y lo que comentas "El error sale, pero...solo al utilizar la terminal integrada que trae el editor, que si no me equivoco es "Power Shell". Si ejecuto el archivo java desde una terminal cmd, el programa no lanza una excepción, aunque los caracteres siguen sin mostrarse correctamente si llevan acentos o "ñ"."
:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Prueba");
  String palabre = teclado.nextLine();
  String frase = "texté " + palabre;
  System.out.println(frase);
}
```

De acuerdo a tu ejemplo, si se escriben caracteres acentuados o con tilde seguramente obtendrás lo siguiente, ejemplo:

Entrada:

```
Canción cada año de emoción
```

Salida:

```
texté Canci�n cada a�o de emoci�n
```

**Para solucionar esto, puedes definir a tu Scanner un charset "ISO-8859-1"** :

```
Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in, "ISO-8859-1");
```

de esta forma al realizar la entrada:

```
Canción cada año de emoción
```

tendrás como salida:

```
texté  cañon Canción cada año de emoción
```

Comment: Da igual el tipo de encoding que ponga al declarar el Scanner, el error persiste.

Con el bucle que has puesto, sí, se puede guardar una cadena, pero eso no soluciona el problema, pues esa cadena no se puede usar ni acceder a ella, entonces, solo es un parche.

Comment: Puedes agregar un poco más de tu código, tal vez tu clase completa ? Me parece que el problema se encuentra en otra parte  @Verboso

Comment: En realidad, el programa es así de sencillo:

`import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prueba {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        
        
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Prueba");

        String palabre = teclado.nextLine();

        String frase = "texté";

        System.out.println(frase);
    }
}`

El problema solo se da al intentar leer cadenas desde la consola.
Es decir, por lo que he podido comprobar, el problema no es Java, es la consola en sí misma.

Comment: @Verboso este código te genera el error: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found ????

Comment: Sí, lo hace. 

El error sale, pero...solo al utilizar la terminal integrada que trae el editor, que si no me equivoco es "Power Shell". Si ejecuto el archivo java desde una terminal cmd, el programa no lanza una excepción, aunque los caracteres siguen sin mostrarse correctamente si llevan acentos o "ñ".

Comment: Entiendo, esto depende en donde ejecutes tu programa, para eso hay que definir una codificación para forzar a que se muestre correctamente, revisa mi actualización con "ISO-8859-1" @Verboso

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129895/discussion-between-verboso-and-jorgesys).